# Matching two data frames with some characters in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frames

```html
df1 <- data.frame(
    Description=c("How are you- doing?", "will do it tomorrow otherwise: next week", "I will work hard to complete it for nextr week1 or  tomorrow", "I am HAPPY with this situation now","Utilising this approach can helpα'x-ray", "We need to use interseting <U+0452> books to solve the issue", "Not sure if we could do it appropriately.", "The schools and Universities are closed in f -blook for a week",  "Things are hectic here and we are busy"))
```

```html
   

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

and I want to get the following table:

```html
d <- data.frame(
    Description=c("Utilising this approach can helpa'x-ray", "How are you- doing", " We need to use interseting <U+0452> books to solve the issue ", " will do it tomorrow otherwise: next week ", " Things are hectic here and we are busy ", "I will work hard to complete it for nextr week1 or  tomorrow ", "The schools and Universities are closed in f -blook for a week",  " I am HAPPY with this situation now "," I will work hard to complete it for nextr week1 or  tomorrow"))
    f2<- read.table(text="B12 B6 B9
No Yes Yes
12 6 9
No No Yes
No No Yes
No No Yes
Yes No Yes
11 No Yes
12 11 P
No No Yes

", header=TRUE)

df3<-cbind(d,f2)
```

As you can see in the Description column, there are space and colon, and so on 1 after week is subscript and I was unable to fix it. I want to match it based on "Description". So I want to match df1 with df2 using Description.  Can we do it it in R for this case?

Comment: FYI you misspelled `read.table`

Comment: I couldn't run your example code (even after fixing the misspelling)

Comment: So you want to exchange the first column of `df2` with the first of `df1`? something  like df2[, 1] <- df1[, 1]??

Comment: You can use `dput` to get your data as R code.

Comment: Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: Yes, thank you. So `df1` and `df2` are two different dataframes? How does the value change from `df2` to `out`?

Comment: I am confused. What is `out` then? What is the logic to generate it.

Comment: Can you explain with an example 2-3 rows of how you match the data?

Comment: A bit messy during editing, sorry

Comment: Can you try `fuzzyjoin::stringdist_left_join(df1, df3, by = 'Description')` if that is what you need?

Comment: Yes, but one does have NA NA NA, can we sort it out?

Comment: Use `na.omit` to remove them? `na.omit(fuzzyjoin::stringdist_left_join(df1, df3, by = 'Description'))`

Comment: Great!. Thanks Please submit it as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `stringdist` joins from `fuzzyjoin` package to match data based on `'Description'`. We use `na.omit` to remove the `NA` rows from the final dataframe.

```
na.omit(fuzzyjoin::stringdist_left_join(df1, df3, by = 'Description'))
```